# Compact, connected subset of R^n is pathwise connected?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, path-connected

Let $D$ be a compact, connected $Jordan$ domain in $R^n$ with positive volume, and suppose that the fuction $f:D →R$ is continuous. Show that there is a point $x$ in $D$ in which
$f(x)=(1/volD)$$\int$$f$ over $D$. 
 (Mean Value Property for integral)

I can prove it when $D$ is pathwise connected

But i have no idea when $D$ is just connected

Is it true compact, connected subset of $R^n$ is pathwise connected?

Or is there any other ways to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The standard example is the *Topologist sine curve*:
$$
\Bigl\{\Bigl(x,\sin\frac{1}{x}\Bigr):0<x\le1\Bigr\}\bigcup\{0\}\times[-1,1].
$$
To prove the MVT all you need is that the continuous image of a connected set is connected.

Comment: You example does not have positive volume.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Take the union with the square $[-1,0]\times[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Explaining better the second question, notice that since $D$ is a compact connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ its image $f(D)$ through continuous function $f$ is also compact and connected. Thus, we have $f(D) = [\min_D f, \max_D f]$
 or in other words:
$$ \min_D f \le f(x) \le \max_D f, \text{for every $x \in D$.}$$
Just to emphasize, the answer to your first question is **yes** when $n = 1$ but **no** when $n \geq 2$. Integrating over $D$ and dividing by $\text{Vol}(D)$ one gets
$$ \min_D f \le \frac{1}{\text{Vol}(D)}\int_D f(x) \le \max_D f .$$
But this means that there is $x_0 \in D$ with $f(x_0) = \frac{1}{\text{Vol}(D)}\int_D f(x)$.